# Framework to enable Android and PC data transfer over Wifi, Bluetooth, or USB?

Tags: android, windows, controls, wireless, transfer

I am writing a Windows application that controls an Android mobile wirelessly, such as sending sms, making calls, viewing files, retrieving sensor data, etc. I am simply using IP socket via WiFi, but client has to know the ip address to connect to the server. 
I  was wondering if there is a Framework/API that enable such data transfer no matter over wifi, bluetooth or any other connection methods, and also has kinda auto discovery mechanism? I heard about Intel CCF (Common Connection Framework), but couldn't find valid reference. Do you know any others? MTP?

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small Open Source utility called [cross copy](http://cross-copy.net) to do this kind of things. While there is a web App which enables you do do inter-device copy & paste, the RESTful API below may be what you need. The basic concept is that you connect devices through a server by sharing a common code word.

I suggest you show a short generated code word (like 'a9b3c') in you app and open a listening request in the background (long polling):

```
GET   http://cross-copy.net/api/a9b3c
```

Then your Windows application should have a "link to device" text field where a code word can be entered. You can verify that there is a device listening by calling

```
GET   http://cross-copy.net/api/a9b3c?watch=listeners&count=0
```

If you want to send an sms from the Windows application, you just execute a PUT request onto the code word with some kind of data structure you app can understand (eg. json, xml,...):

```
PUT http://cross-copy.net/api/a9b3c
    { 'command' : 'send sms', 'number' : '0913342133', 'msg' : 'the message which has been typed on the pc' }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 WiFi modes/protocols that may assist you:

1. [SoftAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoftAP) mode - your desktop WiFi device acts as a hotspot and your android device connects to it just like to a normal AP. Supported on Win7/8 if the device driver supports.
2. [WiFi Direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) - protocol that allows 2 WiFi devices to be connected in a P2P network without the mediation of an AP, it's a natural extension on SoftAP mode. Supported on Win7/8 if device driver supports.
3. WiFi [IBSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_Basic_Service_Set) mode - older protocol for data exchange between two devices. Supported on any 802.11-compliant (WiFi) system.